# How to pull mmcblk0 to a windows pc?

Tags: adb, windows, shell

So here is what i want to pull : `mmcblk0` whith it's size 15.7 GB.

```
C:\adb>adb shell
shell@android:/ $ su
su
shell@android:/ # fdisk -l /dev/block/mmcblk0
fdisk -l /dev/block/mmcblk0

Disk /dev/block/mmcblk0: 15.7 GB, 15758000128 bytes
1 heads, 16 sectors/track, 1923584 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16 * 512 = 8192 bytes
```

This is what I tried:

```
C:\adb>adb shell su busybox cat /dev/block/mmcblk0 > C:\1.bin
```

I only have 1KB output with content inside said "unknown id". Also tried with `pull` but seems also doesn't work.

What should I do to get this 15.7 GB mmcblk0  ?

Answer (score 2):

Try: `dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 of=/sdcard/something.bin`

You can do that in a [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yarolegovich.materialterminal&hl=en) or ADB shell. 
It requires only root access.

You can then pull this file to your desktop. I don't know of a way to do it simultaneously.

Comment: Would this include the recovery image as well?

Answer (score 0):

1. Show Developer Options (`Settings > Developer> tap build 7 times`)
2. Enable USB Debugging (`Settings > Developer > USB Debugging`)
3. use TWRP recovery to avoid OS root limitations

   `adb reboot recovery`
4. check your mount points

   `adb shell mount | FINDSTR /R /C:"^/dev"`
5. do the pull

   `adb pull /dev/block/mmcblk0 mmcblk0.img`

For those using a unix like system use `grep` instead of `FINDSTR`;

```
./adb shell mount | grep -P "^/dev" | perl -pe 's/ .*//g' | sort -u
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/cache
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/modem
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/persist
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata
/dev/fuse
```

Comment: You cannot `adb pull` a device, sorry – so that won't work. Not even in recovery.

Comment: Strange. If you check [ADB pull error: remote object '/dev/block/mmcblk0p24' not a file or directory](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/143853/16575), it just gave `remote object '/dev/block/mmcblk0' not a file or directory` – which is what I had expected here.

Comment: @user1133275 you might have a point there – but then `dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 of=/sdcard/something.bin` shouldn't have worked either. If you checked that yourself and it worked for you, guess we've simply got to believe you and add "this might not always work. If it doesn't, use the other approach" :)

Answer (score 0):

if you're in shell, you could use **sh** instead of **su**

from windows, using ADB, set the device in a custom recovery then from a cmd window:

```
adb remount
adb root
adb shell
```

if done while the device is in **recovery mode** (and ***not*** *bootloader* or *sideload*) you would drop into a terminal/command line with "**~:**" instead of "**shell@android:**" then proceed with:

```
cat /dev/block/mmcblk0 > /sdcard/mmcblk0.img
```

*[then there's no need to use sh since you're already in as shell]* and then open another separate cmd window from your pc to pull the file you made (20-30 mins ago****) and use:

```
adb pull /sdcard/mmcblk0.img
```

you can name "mmcblk0.img" to whatever you want it just needs an output file name and extension

****HOWEVER, please be aware and be patient when you run cat, because the cmd window in windows wont show anything while it's "creating" the 15gb .img file, it will just show a line break in the cmd window and seem to provide no response as it processes your command. And you'll know it's finished when you get a fresh line to enter a new command.
since its over 15gb, if your device doesnt have that much storage space to create the file on, you can change the output path after ">" to /storage/sdcard1/mmcblk0.img or what have you, but be sure to have a fast (class 10 or better) microsd because 15gb will take a while to write. Id estimate around half an hour on an external micro sd.

aside from that, why would you want to extract that? it would make more sense if you asked about mmcblk0p05 or mmcblk0p03 but ehh, if you're not planning to read through the binaries by hex then i guess to every man (or woman) his (her) own...

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, you've done nothing wrong but the way you run `su`.
From `su --help` (SuperSU Version 2.79):

> Usage#2: su LOGIN COMMAND...

Thus, you should run

```
C:\adb>adb shell su root busybox cat /dev/block/mmcblk0 > C:\1.bin
```

and everything's fine.