# ADB pull error: remote object '/dev/block/mmcblk0p24' not a file or directory

Tags: adb, data-recovery, partitions

I'm trying to pull the partition /dev/block/mmcblk0 directly to my Windows PC, following the instructions from: [How to pull mmcblk0 to a windows pc?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125135/how-to-pull-mmcblk0-to-a-windows-pc) while the phone is in TWRP, using the command:

```
adb pull /dev/block/mmcblk0 mmcblk0.img
```

But it keeps returning the error:

```
remote object '/dev/block/mmcblk0' not a file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Additional information:
The reason that I want to do this is because I want to restore deleted files from a Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini (GT-I9195), so I need the entire partition.

Comment: It looks like you only read the question you linked to, not the answers. The question specifically asks why the command you mentioned doesn't work, and [Rhaegar's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/125137/12442) explains what you have to do instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`adb pull` is for files.  `/dev/block/mmcblk0` is a block device.  user1133275's answer to that question doesn't work; try the other one, i.e. run `adb shell` and then:

```
$ su
# dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 of=/sdcard/something.bin
```

Then you can run `adb pull /sdcard/something.bin`.